# Reading user input with various parameters

Tags: c, io, user-input, scanf, fgets

I'm trying to read user input that will be taken in as commands and certain methods will be executed based on the input. For example, the input could be:

```
allocate 3
write 3 ABC 10
quit
```

Each part of the inputs are crucial parameters for their respective methods. I've been trying to figure out how to use `scanf()` and `fgets()` to account for the variation in input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [fgets()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) and [strtok()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) combined and you can get down to something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
   char mystring [100];
   char *pch;
   while( fgets (mystring , 100 , stdin) ) /* break with ^D or ^Z */
   {
       //puts (mystring);
       pch = strtok (mystring," ,.-");
        while (pch != NULL)
        {
            // do someting with pch, check if it's a command or an argument
            printf ("%s\n",pch);
            pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
        }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
write 3 ABC 10

write
3
ABC
10
```